# ImageIO not printing proper color

Tags: java, image, colors, graphics2d, javax.imageio

I am trying to read a PNG image file from disk, draw some rectangles on it and save the modified image on the disk. Here's the scala code:

```
//l is a list of Rectangle objects of the form (x1,x2,y1,y2)

val image = ImageIO.read(sourceimage);
val graph=image.createGraphics()
graph.setColor(Color.GREEN)
l.foreach(x=>graph.draw(new java.awt.Rectangle(x.x1,x.y1,x.x2-x.x1,x.y2-x.y1)))
graph.dispose()
ImageIO.write(image,"png",new File(destimage))
```

The rectangles are drawn but in `GREY` color instead of `GREEN`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the source image a color image?

Comment: No I guess. Is there a way to convert it to color image while reading as in PIL ?

Comment: No idea about PIL. but I'd create a second `BufferedImage` with a type of `TYPE_ARGB` and paint the original image to it, then paint the rectangles to the `BufferedImage`, saving it instead...

Comment: Thanks, if you don't mind, could you please show me how to do that? I have no idea with image processing  in java. All the examples I see create a `BufferdImage` like new BufferedImage(800, 600, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB), but not from another `BufferedImage`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the source image is a gray scale image, then it's unlikely that it will be capable of using any color of any sort.

Instead, you need to create a second, colored, `BufferedImage` and paint the original to it.

```
 BufferedImage original = ImageIO.read(sourceimage);
 BufferedImage iamge = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
 Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
 g2d.drawImage(original, 0, 0, null);
 // Continue with what you have
```

Sorry, I have no experience with PIL, but that's how you'd do it (basically) in pure Java

Comment: Awesome! This works. There are some typos: 
`iamge=new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_ARGB)`; should probably be `image=new BufferedImage(original.getWidth(), original.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB)`. If you wanted to edit.

Comment: Thanks for info about the typo ;), glad it could help